# Kafka spark stream: java.lang.InterruptedException

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am a naive when it comes to spark and big data processing. I am writing a spark job where I am consuming stream from kafka and do multiple aggregation on that stream and sometimes I have to create window streams from kafka direct stream.

**Currently I have only two aggregations to perform but in future I may have many different aggregations over widows of multiple time interval.**

The batch interval is 60 seconds.

Below is my code.

```
val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60));

val rawStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams));

// transform creates a new rdd so I thought if I create a new rdd than each of different aggregations will have different rdd's to perform actions
val rViewStream = rawStream.transform((rdd) => rdd);

val rawStreamValues = rViewStream.map(x => x.value());

val windowStream = rawStreamValues.window(Minutes(10), Seconds(60));

windowStream.foreachRDD(windowRDD => ({
  var windowDf = sqlContext.read.json(windowRDD);
  // perform some aggregation on this data frame and push results to redis
}));

rawStream.foreachRDD(x => ({
   // perform some aggregation/transformation on this stream and save to hdfs.
   val stringRDD = x.map(cr => ({
     cr.value();
   }))
   val rawDf = sqlContext.read.json(stringRDD);    <---- exception here
}))
```

The complete exception stack

```
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1988)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1.apply(RDD.scala:1089)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.InferSchema$.infer(InferSchema.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader$$anonfun$3.apply(DataFrameReader.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader$$anonfun$3.apply(DataFrameReader.scala:329)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:328)
```

1. How can I resolve this error ?
2. I am looking for suggestions as to how I can implement the desired scenario in best way possible following best practises.

Comment: at first when I read this I thought you were saying "I am a native with spark" but had just made a typo -- quite the opposite meaning! also FYI "naive" is an adjective. :)

Comment: did you find answer to this?